Объясните кто-нибудь смысл тестов
Предлагаю вам вопрос всей моей жизни после 1-го курса университета.
Тезис: тесты нужны чтобы не проверять код вручную, следовательно не тратить лишнее время.
Антитезис: для каждой новой реализации функции нужны новые тесты, то-есть тратится время, примерно эквивалентное на ручную проверку, после же подтверждения работоспособности функции проверка её не требуется, от чего написанные тесты становятся бесполезны, поскольку изменение рабочей функции не планируется (мы ведь модифицируем, а не изменяем).
Так какой же итог? Мне кто-нибудь когда-нибудь объяснит, как именно тесты сокращают рутину?
(к слову я даже не приступал к их изучению, просто сложно изучать что-то, что заведомо считаешь бесполезным).

У вас есть одно фундаментальное упущение в рассуждениях. Тесты нужны для проверки работоспособности функции В БУДУЩЕМ. Другими словами — для отлова регрессий. Ещё другими словами — чтобы убедиться, что ранее работавшая функция не сломалась после новых изменений. Каждый раз вручную проверять и перепроверять и ещё раз перепроверять, что каждая функция работает после любого мелкого обновления в проекте — замучаетесь

По тексту вопроса: «изменение рабочей функции не планируется» — вот это полная чушь, в реальных проектах всё всегда безостановочно меняется, в том числе и то, что прямо или косвенно затрагивает рабочую функцию; «модифицируем, а не изменяем» — и это тоже полная чушь, ведь оба этих слова означают одно и то же

А вообще даже менять что-либо в проекте иногда не надо: банальная замена процессора может привести к тому, что всё сломается. Так что прям совсем в идеале тесты нужно гонять на как можно большем числе окружений и устройств — на сколько не жалко денег. И желательно не один раз, а постоянно повторять и повторять — с целью вывяления внезапных изменений в окружении или плавающих багов. Ну а там уже и до фаззинга недалеко

дополню к комментариям выше ---> "для каждой новой реализации функции нужны новые тесты, то-есть тратится время, примерно эквивалентное на ручную проверку"  --- это совершеннейшая неправда! Есть какая-то функция, до которой пользователю надо проделать 10 шагов: открыть модальное окно, выбрать значение, нажать ещё что-то в зависимости от предыдущего значения, откроется ещё одна модалка с подтверждением "Сформировать". Вручную это минут 5. Тестом - 2 секунды. Причём тестом можно прогнать 100 сценариев (зависимости от выбора на шаге), а вручную вы сколько будете гонять 100 сценариев?

Тесты не нужны. Тесты вам пригодятся, когда вы начнёте делать сложную работу. Когда вы не будете уверены в правильности кода. Когда вам понадобится убедить себя и других что "это" работает. Когда вы соберете систему из десятка кусков, написанных пятью людьми, а она не заработает с первого раза. Когда она заработает, но со скоростью черепахи. Когда она заработает быстро, но начнёт сыпать ошибками.

"Тесты не нужны." - уточню: тесты вам не нужны, пока вы пишете одноразовые программы типа лаб и курсовых. И ваш антитезис предполагает, что вы тесты написали, запустили один раз, и никогда больше запускать не будете. В реальных проектах код нужно поддерживать длительное время, и однажды написанные тесты экономят огромное количество времени в будущем.

А вот авария, стоимостью 500 млн$ произошедшая из за отсутствия тестирования функции в новом окружении https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%C2%AB%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD-5%C2%BB
